# How can i change direction each time one direction?

Tags: unity, c#

I have two scripts the first one is class not monobehaviour:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightsEffects
{
    private Renderer[] renderers;
    private float lastChangeTime;
    private int greenIndex = 0;
    private bool shouldChangeDirection = false;

    public void LightsEffect(List<GameObject> objects, Color instantiateColor, Color colorEffect)
    {
        renderers = new Renderer[objects.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        {
            renderers[i] = objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderers[i].material.color = Color.red;
        }

        // Set green color to the first one
        greenIndex = 0;
        renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Running the effect
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isReversed">Changing the lights movement directions - false = forward, true = backward.</param>
    public void LightsEffectCore(float delay, bool isReversed)
    {
        // Change color each `delay` seconds
        if (Time.time > lastChangeTime + delay)
        {
            lastChangeTime = Time.time;

            // Set color of the last renderer to red
            // and the color of the current one to green
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.red;

            if (shouldChangeDirection)
            {
                Array.Reverse(renderers);
                isReversed = !isReversed;
            }

            greenIndex = (greenIndex + 1) % renderers.Length;
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
        }
    }
}
```

And in this script the part i'm trying to set what direction is:

```
if (shouldChangeDirection)
                {
                    Array.Reverse(renderers);
                    isReversed = !isReversed;
                }
```

The problem is that i'm using this class in another monobehaviour script:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform traveller;
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public Transform nextWaypoint;
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float slowDownSpeed = 3f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
    public float distancetoRotate = 3f;
    public bool random = false;
    public bool reverse = false;
    public int howmanylight = 5;
    public Generatenumbers gn;
    public LightsEffects lightseffect;
    public bool changeLightsDirection = false;

    private int targetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    private List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();


    private bool rotateNumber = false;
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint").OrderBy(go => go.name).ToArray();
        if (random == false)
        {
            targetsIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            targetsIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
        }
        originalPosition = traveller.position;

        GameObject go1 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        duplicateObject(go1, howmanylight);

        lightseffect = new LightsEffects();
        lightseffect.LightsEffect(objects, Color.red, Color.green);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        WayPointsAI();

        if (rotateNumber == true)
        {
            gn.newTexts[currentIndex].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10 * 50 * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(0.1f, changeLightsDirection);
    }

    private void WayPointsAI()
    {
        if (targetsIndex == waypoints.Length)
            targetsIndex = 0;

        nextWaypoint = waypoints[targetsIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(traveller.transform.position, nextWaypoint.transform.position);
        traveller.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(traveller.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(nextWaypoint.position - traveller.transform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (reverse == true)
        {
            var targetAngles = traveller.transform.eulerAngles + 180f * Vector3.up;
            traveller.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(traveller.transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            var lastWaypoint = waypoints[currentIndex];
            Array.Reverse(waypoints);
            reverse = false;
        }

        if (distance < distancetoRotate)
        {
            traveller.transform.position += traveller.transform.forward * slowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            traveller.transform.position += traveller.transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (distance < nextWaypoint.transform.localScale.magnitude)
        {
            rotateNumber = true;
            currentIndex = targetsIndex;

            if (random == false)
            {
                targetsIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                targetsIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    public void duplicateObject(GameObject original, int howmany)
    {
        howmany++;
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < howmany; j++)
            {
                Vector3 position = waypoints[i].transform.position + j * (waypoints[i + 1].transform.position - waypoints[i].transform.position) / howmany;
                GameObject go = Instantiate(original, new Vector3(position.x, 0, position.z), Quaternion.identity);
                go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.3f, 0.1f, 0.3f);
                objects.Add(go);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the top of the waypoints script i have two lines:

```
public LightsEffects lightseffect;
public bool changeLightsDirection = false;
```

Then in the Start i'm creating instance for the LightsEffect:

```
lightseffect = new LightsEffects();
```

Then in the Update i want to be able to change the direction of the lights false/true states:

```
lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(0.1f, changeLightsDirection);
```

The problem is that no matter if changeLightsDirection is false or true since in the Lights Effect class i'm using: shouldChangeDirection and it's true all the time.

Anyway it's not working when the game is running and i change the changeLightsDirection state in the waypoints script it's not effecting the LighsEffect direction it's not reversing the array each time.

In the Lights Effect class/script i'm using:

```
if (shouldChangeDirection)
```

Since i want to track the state of the array reversing.
What i did before was: is just checking if isReversed false or true but then if it's on true or false state all the time it will keep reversing the array non stop.

I messed up all the flags in both scripts.

Comment: [I downvoted this question because it contains too much code.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Let me try to describe what I think of the problem:

you have a flag to keep track if you should change direction in this method call:

```
private bool shouldChangeDirection = false;
```

then you are passing it to the method

```
lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(0.1f, changeLightsDirection);
```

to base reverse operation on it.

---

Here is what I think you should do:

Change method definition to this:

```
public void LightsEffectCore(float delay, ref bool isReversed)
```

Notice the `ref` keyword, it will modify the variable passed as the parameter.

Now in `LightsEffectCore()` method:

```
if (!isReversed)
{
    Array.Reverse(renderers);
}

isReversed = !isReversed;
```

And remove

```
private bool shouldChangeDirection = false;
```

from `LightsEffects` class as it's not being used anymore.

---

**UPDATE:**

You don't need to reverse the array, alternatively, you can use *First* and *Last* elements in the array using `Linq`:

firstly, add `using System.Linq;` at the start of the file.

then use this code:

```
if (isReversed)
{
    renderers.Last().material.color = Color.green;
    greenIndex = renderers.Length-1;
}
else
{
    renderers.First().material.color = Color.green;
    greenIndex = 0;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried your solution now. What it does is changing the flag false/true all the time every frame automatic i don't do anything running the game and it's changing the flag false/true nonstop. In the other script the waypoints i did: lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(0.1f, ref changeLightsDirection); and in the LightsEffect i changed the method like you did: public void LightsEffectCore(float delay, ref bool isReversed) and inside i did the if (!isReversed) and the isReversed = !isReversed;

Comment: I forgot my log in user name before and used a guest now i entered with my user name again if not i can't add comment. Sorry for that.

Comment: @DanielLip when do you want to change the flag?

Comment: When i change in the other script the waypoints script the flag when the game is running and i change the flag to false/true i want it to change the direction in LightsEffect. The line in waypoints: lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(0.1f, ref changeLightsDirection); The flag changeLightsDirection is public when i change it to false or true change the direction in LightsEffect script in the LightsEffectCore method.

Comment: I have added an update to my answer. let me know if it works.

Comment: You need to update greenIndex as you are using it in LightsEffect() method. Check the update

Comment: Working. But i can't mark it as solved since i'm using my account now and can't log in as the guest before. Sorry for all the mess.

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful.